# How to query one to many relationship in Dapper and return grouped object

Tags: .net, dapper

I have this sql:

```
SELECT I.*, IG.Id 
FROM Images I 
JOIN ImageGroup IG ON I.ImageGroupId = IG.Id 
WHERE IG.Id = @imageGroupId
```

*(Lets suppose in addition to `IG.Id` we have other columns, because we already have the id)*

I need to return an object `ImageGroup` with the Id and the other columns and a List of Images. I don't want the `IEnumerable<ImageGroup>` that Dapper's Query returns.

How can you do that with Dapper in the most efficient and expected way?

Comment: You need to learn to work with `IEnumerable<T>`. You can use it directly with a foreach loop and nearly every linq operation (.Where(), .Select(), etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the most efficient and logic way to do it is with QueryMultiple. So the code would be like this one:

```
        var sql =
            @"
                SELECT * FROM Images WHERE ImageGroupId = @imageGroupId;
                SELECT * FROM ImageGroups WHERE Id = @imageGroupId;
            ";

        var grids = await connection.QueryMultipleAsync(
            sql,
            new { imageGroupId });

        var images = grids.Read<Image>();
        var imageGroup = grids.ReadSingle<ImageGroup>();
        imageGroup.Images = images.AsList();

        return imageGroup;
```

Answer (score 0):

On the memory side, you should perform group by `ImageGroup`'s `ID` via `.GroupBy()`.

```cs
public class ImageGroup
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public List<Image> Images { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
using System.Linq;

var image = connection.Query<ImageModel>(/* Your SQL query */)
    .GroupBy(x => x.ID)
    .Select(x => new ImageGroup
    {
        ID = x.Key,
        Images = x.Select(y => new Image
        {
            // Assign value to properties
        })
        .ToList()
    })
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

And with the `FirstOrDefault()` at the las, this will result a single `ImageGroup` object.